# Different font for unnumbered parts in KOMA-Script

Tags: fonts, koma-script, parts

I can set the font of elements as follows:

```
\addtokomafont{part}{\normalfont\huge\raggedright}
```

How can I change the font **only** for unnamed parts, i.e. `part*`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: I'd be not surprised, if somebody asked for a different layout of unnumbered sections. But a different font for the part-title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change the alignment of the headings in the foot settings.

With an uptodate KOMA-Script version (3.25 or newer) you could patch `\partlineswithprefixformat` to get a different font and a different alignment for numbered and unnumbered parts.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2018/03/30]% needs version 3.25 or newer
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand*\raggedpart{\centering}
\newcommand*\raggedunnumberedpart{\raggedright}
\newkomafont{unnumberedpart}{\normalfont\huge}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\partlineswithprefixformat{%
  \ifstr{#1}{part}
    {\IfArgIsEmpty{#2}
      {\raggedunnumberedpart
       \addtokomafont{part}{\usekomafont{unnumberedpart}}%
      }{}%
    }{}%
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\part{Numbered part}
\lipsum[1]
\addpart{Unnumbered part}
\lipsum[2]
\addpart*{Second unnumbered part}
\lipsum[3-4]
\part{Second numbered part}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]